# How to push data to sdcard/Android/data on Firmware 11

Tags: android, adb

I usually use `adb` to push data from my PC - Windows 10 to Android devices with the command `adb push data /sdcard/Android/data/PackageName` or `sdcard/Android/obb/PackageName`. Everything works fine until Android 11.

I just notice that I cannot push on some devices such as Samsung S20, other Manufatures ... However, Pixel 3 with FW11 works.
I also test with Android 12 Beta 1, Pixel 5, and the issue happens too.

My Android Debug Bridge version is `1.0.41`

Do you have any idea about this issue? Or Google has note that somewhere? Can we use the adb to push data as before?

Comment: Added link to [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191543922)

Comment: Google said they solved this issue on next firmware update. But I don't know when and which update :D